# Import a .sql file to a MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to import a SQL file through the command line interface.

I have tried the following code:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

This gives me a `syntax error`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that syntax looks fine, what output did it give?  does the user you're specifying have the appropriate permissions for that database?

Comment: it is giving Syntax error

Comment: The syntax error is located *in the sql file*, not in the command (if the error message came from the mysql server). Check the file and correct any errors.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, there is probably an error on your SQL file. Try breaking it to smaller chunks to find the error.

Comment: Now, I used ' -uroot -proot database name ' and then 'source (path)\filename.sql ' and it is working..Now the problem which i am facing is that from the command prompt it is showing all the tables which are contaning in that file but when I am accessing it through MySQL it only shows the database name not the tables or any data in that

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
mysql -u <username> -p <database> < textfile.sql
```

If you do it like this the file needs to be in the same directory you are currently in. If you know where the file is you can do:

```
mysql -u <username> -p <database> < /path/to/file/textfile.sql
```

Comment: OP wants to import, which is done with the < character.